# The best approach to index dynamic query in MongoDB

Tags: performance, mongodb, indexing

I am working on log managment system where user will be able to upload logs from file. I have 'event' collection where I store all events from all sources (each source can have different log format and in one collection I can have e.g. 10 000 000 records - 5 000 000 for 'source1' and 5 000 000 for 'source2'). I want to provide filter option to the user  (filter option will be only for source so user can filter data by level, data etc) and for better performance I want to create indexes and also compound indexes. Before user upload logs to the system he/she will decide what filter queries wants to use during filtering. So I can have different queries. The problem is that I can have many different sources in one collection and that mean many different filter queries but mongoDB only allow 64 indexes per collection.

So what is the best solution if I want have good read performance and I want let user to filter logs (the user will decide how he wants to filter data before logs will be uploaded to the sytem)? I was thinking to create new collection for each source as I will never reach 64 indexes per collection.

*Queries sample:*

```
db.events.ensureIndex({"source_id": 1, "timestamp" : 1})
db.events.ensureIndex({"source_id": 1, "timestamp" : 1, "level": 1})
db.events.ensureIndex({"source_id": 1, "diagnostic_context": 1})
db.events.ensureIndex({"source_id": 1, "timestamp" : 1, "statusCode": 1})
db.events.ensureIndex({"source_id": 1, "host" : 1})
```

*Event collection sample:*

```
{   _id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439011"),
    timestamp: ISODate("2012-09-27T03:42:10Z"),
    thread: "[http-8080-3]",
    level: "INFO",
    diagnostic_context: "User 99999",
    message: "existing customer saving"},
    source_id: "source1"
{   _id: ObjectId("507f1f77bcf86cd799439012"),
    host: "144.18.39.44",
    timestamp: ISODate("2012-09-01T03:42:10Z"),
    request: "GET /resources.html HTTP/1.1",
    statusCode: 200
    bytes_sent: 3458,
    url: "http://www.aivosto.com/",
    agent: "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)",
    source_id: "source2"
}
```

Comment: I would agree that a collection per source could a good solution for this. From the example records provided there is not a lot of field overlap between sources. I don't see an advantage to having all in a single collection unless you have a use case requiring.